# How to deselect a selected entry in a List?

Tags: sapui5

in my app I use this code in my xml-view to create a List. Now I can select an entry of the list. I use this entry to filter the values of the detailPage. But how can I deselect an entry, so that nothing is selected?

```xml
            <List id="guList" items="{statusData>/SurveySet}" includeItemInSelection="false" mode="SingleSelectMaster" select="filterChange">
                <StandardListItem
                    title='{path: "statusData>text", formatter: ".formatter.emptyText"}'
                    description='{path: "statusData>id", formatter: ".formatter.stringToInt"}'
                    type="Active"/>
            </List>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke [`removeSelections`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#removeSelections) on `List` object with an argument as `true` to remove all selections.

```
this.getView().byId("guList").removeSelections(true);
```

To remove particular item's selection use [`setSelectedItem`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#setSelectedItem) with item to be removed as first argument and it's boolean value as second.

In your case it will be like

```
this.getView().byId("guList").setSelectedItem(oListItem, false);
```

Further, you can get currently selected item within `selectionChange` event handler, which you can preserve and use it to remove selection later on as and when required.

Comment: And when I only want to deselect if the selected is pressed?

Comment: if you want to keep older selections, do not pass boolean 
`this.getView().byId("guList").removeSelections();`

Comment: Yes, but I want only to deselect the current item if it is currently the selected one.

Comment: check modified answer, hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, but what event can I use? The select-event is only fired at the first selection and not at the second click.

Comment: Nope, `select` event is fired for every selection. [Here](http://jsbin.com/totakek/edit?html,js,output) is working exapmle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113584/discussion-between-dopedev-and-gerrit).